# Proof that $|1 - e^{i \theta}| \geq \frac{2|\theta|}{\pi}$ for $-\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, exponential-function

I would like to prove (geometrically if possible) the above result. Could someone help?

Comment: Are you familiar with the unit circle in the complex plane being parameterized by $e^{i\theta}$?

Comment: yes, I was hoping to use that as the basis of a geometric proof.

Comment: @hardmath that makes the result intuitive, but as far as I can tell it doesn't indicate an obvious geometric proof.

Comment: Isn't this false at $\theta=\pi$? The LHS would be $|1-i|=\sqrt{2}$ and the RHS would be $2$.

Comment: @ScottDallas we can show geometrically that
$$
\frac{|1 - e^{i \theta}|}{|\theta|} = \frac{\sin(\theta/2)}{(\theta/2)}
$$
and we can then find a lower bound for this function using the fact that it's monotonic over $\theta$.  However, I don't know if this is a sufficiently "geometric" proof for your purposes.  Also, the same result can be derived by expanding the numerator with Euler's identity.

Comment: @TrevorNorton, $e^{i\pi}=-1$

Comment: @vrugtehagel Oh duh.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks, that could be sufficient. How would we then find the lower bound?

Comment: Note that $f(\theta) = \frac{\sin(\theta/2)}{(\theta/2)}$ is even and is decreasing from $0$ to $\pi$.  I'm not sure how one would show that this function is decreasing without some calculus, though.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, that works. But how do we show that $f'(\theta) = \frac{\theta \cos(\theta/2) - 2 sin(\theta/2)}{\theta^2}$ is less than 0 for this range of $\theta$?

Comment: @ScottDallas Oh, that's not bad at all!  Look back at the traditional proof for $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.  It suffices to note that the area of the larger triangle exceeds the area of the sector. Hence, $\tan \theta > \theta^2$.

Comment: Wait... that doesn't quite work for us, I think.... I'm not sure now.

Comment: In any case, we want to prove that
$$
\tan(x) > x
$$
whenever $x > 0$.  Hmm...

Comment: Well, $\frac{d}{dx}\tan(x) = \sec^2(x) > 1 = \frac{d}{dx}(x)$, and by the [racetrack principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racetrack_principle) we're set.

Comment: @ScottDallas does that make sense, or should I put that together in an answer?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom that should be enough for my purposes, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $e^{i\theta}$ is a point on the unit circle in the right half-plane we have
$$ \left\|1-e^{i\theta}\right\| = 2\sin\frac{|\theta|}{2} $$
but over the interval $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ the function $f(x)=\sin(x)$ is a concave function, hence
$$ \sin(x)\geq \frac{2x}{\pi}$$
and
$$ \left\|1-e^{i\theta}\right\| \geq \frac{2|\theta|}{\pi} $$
follows.