# When $- \pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$, $|1 - e^{i\theta}| \geq 2 |\theta|/\pi$

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $\theta$ is a real number with $- \pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$, then I am trying to see why the identity $|1 - e^{i\theta}| \geq 2 |\theta|/\pi$ holds. In this answer [Prove $|e^{i\theta} -1| \leq |\theta|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584498/prove-ei-theta-1-leq-theta), we see that $|e^{i\theta} - 1| \leq |\theta|$ using the fundamental theorem of calculus (among other proofs, some using geometry).

I realize this seems easy but I'm not sure how to show this. If $\theta = \pm \pi$, then  $|e^{i\theta} - 1| = 2 = 2 \frac {|\theta|}{\pi} $, but more generally I am not sure.

Comment: Can you explicitly write $|e^{i \theta} -1|^2$ as a function of $\theta$, involving only sine and/or cosine?

Comment: @MartinR this equality is slightly different, I don't get how one follows from the other. May be obvious i'm just not seeing it right away.

Comment: You are right, this one is the other way around, sorry about that. –  But have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1720357/42969, that should help.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1657293/42969.